# Is there an addon with a similar function as NoScript for the Edge browser?

Tags: microsoft-edge, noscript

I would like to use the Edge Browser because hes faster on my notebook, but from the two addons AdBlock and NoScript, which are important to me, only AdBlock exists for the Edge.

Is there an alternative addon, or information about NoScript for Edge in the future?

Answer (score 1):

At present, No any alternative add on available for Edge like noscript add on.

You can also verify this by visiting the MS Store.

We also don't have any news for noscript add on, When it will be available for Edge.

You can try to visit the official site for noscript add on and ask this question on their forum. Maybe they can give you any information about this add on for Edge support.

[NoScript Add-on](https://noscript.net/)